# Trouble with Native OpenGL Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am using Native code to render OpenGL in Android and I get periodic errors that look like this:

> ERROR/IMGSRV(1435): frameresource.c:610: WaitUntilResourceIsNotNeeded: PVRSRVEventObjectWait failed
>
> ERROR/IMGSRV(1018): sgxif.c:124: WaitForRender: PVRSRVEventObjectWait failed
>
> ERROR/IMGSRV(1435): osfunc_um.c:318: PVRSRVEventObjectWait: Error 13 returned

Once these errors come up I have to restart the phone or the rendering won't start again correctly.  I have done a lot of web searching and I can't find out what could be the cause of these errors.  Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer, but some potentially useful info: I found the symbol PVRSRVEventObjectWait in an [OMAP sgx driver patch](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~cvm/repo/add_nokia_sgx_driver.patch). It appears that something you're doing is pissing off the OMAP graphics drivers. Given the text of the message, I'm going to hazard a guess and say that either a resource is being leaked, or the graphics calls are being used improperly from multiple threads. I wouldn't expect to get a much better answer than that on this site without some test source code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is hard to tell without looking at your code, it can either be a driver issue,
or something wrong in your code.

Try the following:

- Make sure that your GL calls are on the same thread.
- Try commenting out all your rendering code and start adding lines back, till you see the problem appears again.
- Check for memory leaks